# copying files from one folder to another

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that copies all the files other than the zipped files from a source folder to another destination folder and extract zipped files from the source folder to the destination, this is what i have come till this far:

```
    import os
    import zipfile
    import shutil
    myPath = "Source dir"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.zip'):
                fh = open(file, 'rb')
                z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
                for name in z.namelist():
                    outpath = "destination dir"#Put the name of the          destination folder
                    z.extract(name, outpath)
                fh.close()
            else:
                fileList = os.listdir('source dir')
                for f in fileList:
                    shutil.copy2(f, 'destination directory')
```

The code shows no error but there is no output too.

Answer (score 0):

From Python Standard Library *To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name)* so you should write

```
fh = open(so.path.join(root,file))
```

to have the correct path.

Comment: the change you suggested is not working any good.Can you tell me the exact error.

Comment: With the expression I gave you, the path is still relative to 'source path'. You could try `os.path.join(os.path.join('source dir', root), file), replacing 'source dir' by your real source path.